# How can I pass a value to a function when onPress is pressed in Reactnative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using Reactnaitve
When onPress is triggered, the photosModalControl function is executed and I want to get the value first, and I also want to execute setUploadPhotos. But when I use my code, I get the value, but setUploadPhotos is not executed. How do I fix the code?

this is my code

```
const photosModalControl = (value: string) => () =>  {
    console.log(value);
    setUploadPhotos(prevState => !prevState);
};


<Pressable 
onPress={photosModalControl("first")}
>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are passing the function in the onPress will result in that function call on render. Instead use this:

```
    const photosModalControl = (value: string) => () =>  {
        console.log(value);
        setUploadPhotos(prevState => !prevState);
    };


    <Pressable onPress={()=>photosModalControl("first")}>Button</Pressable>
```

This way you can pass any number of arguments to your function

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken, shouldn't you set up your function like this:

```
const someFunction = (variable: type) => {
   functions stuff
}
```

you doubled up and put:

```
const someFunction = (variable: type) = () => {
   functions stuff
}
```